# string sorting csv row

Tags: python, string, csv, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

rawDF = pd.read_csv('D:\Project\python\Grade\GradeDataRaw.csv',names=['GradeCol'])

filteredDF = rawDF[rawDF['GradeCol'].str.contains('EVCS:|BVCS:|LOW POINT STA')]
print(filteredDF)

filename = 'GradeOut.csv'

filteredDF.to_csv(filename,index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Output in CSV file is

GradeCol

```
EVCS: 210+080.907

BVCS: 210+080.907

LOW POINT STA =208+108.133\PLOW POINT ELEV = 66.849\PPVI STA = 209+126.315\PPVI ELEV = 66.762\PA.D = 1.413%\PK

LOW POINT STA =208+108.133\PLOW POINT ELEV = 66.849\PPVI STA = 209+126.000\PPVI ELEV = 66.762\PA.D = 1.413%\PK
```

Would like to have only "PPVI STA = 209+126.315" in data frame row where there is this string available, other rows with EVCS & BVCS to remain intact, numerical part can vary in every row.
With the extract method getting NaN values in the rows where the is no match , that is not the intention.

Comment: What is your desired output?  do you want to order all the rows?

Comment: `"info \GPK HEK = 209+126.315\info ends here"` - is it the whole string/row or just one column in the row?

Comment: hello guys , hope the above edit with more information helps to clarify the expected output.

Comment: Welcome to the site: you may want to read [help/on-topic], [ask] and [mcve], and re-word your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

Sample DF:

```
In [99]: df
Out[99]:
                                                 txt
0         info \GPK HEK = 209+126.315\info ends here
1  blah-blah-blah GPK HEK = 1 + 2.33333end of string
```

Solution:

```
In [100]: df['txt'].str.extract(r'(GPK HEK\s*=\s*\d+\s*\+\s*\d+\.\d+)', expand=False)
Out[100]:
0    GPK HEK = 209+126.315
1    GPK HEK = 1 + 2.33333
Name: txt, dtype: object
```

Comment: hello MaxU, kindly have a look at the new edited information.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job.

```
def parse(string):
    start = string.find('\\') + 1
    end   = string.find('.')

    while string[end] != '\\':
        end += 1

    return string[start : end]
```